# How can I get code coverage of an external java library with jacoco?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

If I have a java project that uses a library (a jar file), is it possible to get the code coverage of classes inside this jar ?

The idea behind this is that I would like to find out what proportion of the external libraries the project relies on (let's say spring, hibernate, or it could be the scala jars if it was a scala project, why not) are actually used. I even imagine that I could try to list them and rebundle them in a single jar that would contain *only* necessary .class files (with a plugin like apache felix, for example) to get the smallest possible jar. I'm not sure I really want to do this, I'm aware it is probably a bad idea for a number of reasons, but I think of it as an experimentation.

I can't find how to do it, jacoco reports only coverage for the class files directly inside my project. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'm using the maven plugin like this :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.6.201201232323</version>
            <configuration>
                <destfile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destfile>
                <datafile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</datafile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I've tried changing the include tag, but the only effect is restricting the default which includes only the class files directly inside my project.

Thanks in advance !

---

Edit after oers' answer :

I found out how to do it with ant and antrun-plugin, though it is very complicated, I had much trouble with antrun plugin versions (unable to make a recent version work, even for a basic task) and I'd really like to stick to Maven. **If someone knows how to do the equivalent with je jacoco maven plugin instead of ant, I'm interested !**

Partial solution with ant : actually the jacoco.exec file already contained references to the classes of my external jars ; therefore it is the report task that should be told to take account of these jar, and not the runtime phase as I thought. Here is the maven configuration I used (I found help on http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/jacoco-tycho-and-coverage-reports/ ) :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.7</version>-->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                    <version>0.5.6.201201232323</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                    <version>20020829</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-report</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>

                            <taskdef name="jacoco-report"
                                   classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask"
                                   classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                            <taskdef classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath"
                     resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
                            <available
               file="${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec"
               property="jacoco.exec.file.exists" />
                            <echo message="${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec" />
                            <if>
                                <equals arg1="${jacoco.exec.file.exists}"
                      arg2="true" />
                                <then>
                                    <echo message="Executing jacoco report" />

                                    <trycatch>
                                        <try>
                                            <jacoco-report>
                                                <executiondata>
                                                    <file
                                 file="${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec" />
                                                </executiondata>

                                                <structure name="Minerva">
                                                    <classfiles>
                                                        <fileset
                                     dir="target/classes" />

                                                        <fileset dir="C:/Data/dev/m2Repository/com/groupama/framework/crypt/fwk-cryptage/1.0/">
                                                            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                                                        </fileset>

                                                    </classfiles>

                                                    <sourcefiles
                                    encoding="UTF-8">
                                                        <fileset
                                     dir="src/main/java" />
                                                    </sourcefiles>
                                                </structure>
                                                <html destdir="${project.basedir}/target/jacoco/report" />
                                                <xml destfile="${project.basedir}/target/jacoco/report/jacoco.xml"/>
                                            </jacoco-report>
                                        </try>
                                        <catch>
                                            <echo>skipping</echo>
                                        </catch>
                                    </trycatch>
                                </then>
                                <else>
                                    <echo message="No jacoco.exec file found." />
                                </else>
                            </if>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the report goal the classes of the library you want to analyze. Unfortunatly I can't find a documentation on that. [The official docu is ... hm ... sparse](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html)

IF you can execute ant, I'd suggest looking at the [report task](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html).

```
<jacoco:report>

    <executiondata>
        <file file="jacoco.exec"/>
    </executiondata>

    <structure name="Example Project">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="classes"/> <!-- HERE THE CLASSES FROM YOUR LIB -->
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="src"/> <!-- HERE THE SORUCESFROM YOUR LIB -->
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>

    <html destdir="report"/>

</jacoco:report>
```

Comment: You're right about the documentation, which really needs to be more complete. I really thought it was the run task that needed to be parametered ; you made me look into the jacoco.exec file and realize that it already contained references to classes inside external jars, which means that it's the report which needs to be correctly parametered.
Not knowing ant, I spent all the morning before getting it to work, but it finally worked. It partially satisfies me, see my answer below, but it's a step in the right direction. Thanks a lot anyway !

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question is old, it still seems relevant. If the external library is a Maven project, you can go to the library source directory and request JaCoCo report obtained previously with your testsuite from within there:

```
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:report -Djacoco.dataFile=/path/to/jacoco.exec
```

You obtain the report in ${project}/target/site/jacoco directory.